# Shifting from iterator to for each

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

I have a `panel1` function that returns an iterator that works with the following program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

     Iterator<Integer> it = panel1(1,5);
     for(;it.hasNext();)
        System.out.println(it.next()); // return 1 2 3 4 5
}
```

For simplicity, I want to facilitate this by using the Java foreach syntax as shown in the following example.

```
for(int i:panel2(1,5))
    System.out.println(i); // would return 1 2 3 4 5
```

Here is the `Panel` class I did so far with an anonym class:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Panel{

    public static Iterator<Integer> panel1(final int begin,final int end){
        Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>(){

            private int nextValue = begin;
            private final int max = end;

            public boolean hasNext() {
                return nextValue <= max;
            }

            public Integer next() {
                if (!hasNext()) {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
                return Integer.valueOf(nextValue++);
            }

            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
        return it;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Iterator<Integer> it = panel1(1,5);
         for(;it.hasNext();)
            System.out.println(it.next()); // affiche 1 2 3 4 5
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, nice statement. But do you have a question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Iterator`s are not `Iterable` in Java as they are in some other languages, so you have to have `panel1` return an `Iterable<Integer>`, not an `Iterator<Integer>`, and then use it directly in the enhanced `for` loop:

```
public class Panel{

    public static Iterable<Integer> panel1(final int begin,final int end){
        return new Iterable<Integer>() {
            public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
                Iterator<Integer> it = new Iterator<Integer>(){

                    private int nextValue = begin;
                    private final int max = end;

                    public boolean hasNext() {
                        return nextValue <= max;
                    }

                    public Integer next() {
                        if (!hasNext()) {
                            throw new NoSuchElementException();
                        }
                        return Integer.valueOf(nextValue++);
                    }

                    public void remove() {
                        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
                    }
                };
                return it;
            }
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         for (int i : panel1(1,5)) {
            System.out.println(i);
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Do you know how to ensure that the Panel can be treated like any object of type List?

Comment: @ThePassenger - Have `Panel` implement the `List` interface.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Iterable` instead of `Iterator` in the method signature:

```
public static Iterable<Integer> panel1(final int begin,final int end) {
  ...
  return () -> it;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass `Iterable<Integer>` to the enhanced for loop, not an `Iterator<Integer>`.

For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Iterable<Integer> iterable = () -> panel1(1,5);
    for (int i : iterable)
        System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use real `int`s, with [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html):

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
    .forEach(System::println):

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
    .forEach(i -> System.println(i)):

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
    .forEach(i -> System.println(i)):

IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 5)
    .forEach(i -> {
         System.println(i);
}):


1
2
:
5
```

This uses Streams, with the even newer *forEach* construct.

`IntStream.range(1, 6)` would be equivalent, 6 being the *exclusive* upper bound.

Comment: Sadly streams can't be directly used in a java-5 for-each loop